# My JavaScript code seems to block mobile device?

Tags: javascript, events, mobile, key, swipe

I have the following code in one page.
Currently works fine on desktop.
Left arrow navigate backwards. Right arrow goes forward. I want to add something on home and end maybe.

The "swipe" part of the code is something I just got after a web search, except a few lines (if ... else ...) after "//DO STUFF HERE".

Testing on mobile (Firefox on Galagy S4): the site works well except this one which is the only to include the code.

Result: swipe not working but also click (not sure if it is called click on mobile) not work, resize not working ... In other word, stuck on the page.

And I don't have much tools to debug on mobile.

```
function checkKey(event) {
    var keyEvent = event || window.event,
        keycode = (keyEvent.which) ? keyEvent.which : keyEvent.keyCode;
    if(keycode == 37)
        NavigateBackward();
    else if(keycode == 39)
        NavigateForward();
    else
        {
        alert(keycode);
        return true
        }
    return false;
}
document.onkeypress = checkKey;


var swipeFunc = {//Source:https://gist.github.com/localpcguy/1373518
        touches : {
            "touchstart": {"x":-1, "y":-1}, 
            "touchmove" : {"x":-1, "y":-1}, 
            "touchend"  : false,
            "direction" : "undetermined"
        },
        touchHandler: function(event) {
            var touch;
            if (typeof event !== 'undefined'){  
                event.preventDefault(); 
                if (typeof event.touches !== 'undefined') {
                    touch = event.touches[0];
                    switch (event.type) {
                        case 'touchstart':
                        case 'touchmove':
                            swipeFunc.touches[event.type].x = touch.pageX;
                            swipeFunc.touches[event.type].y = touch.pageY;
                            break;
                        case 'touchend':
                            touches[event.type] = true;
                            if (swipeFunc.touches.touchstart.x > -1 && swipeFunc.touches.touchmove.x > -1) {
                                swipeFunc.touches.direction = swipeFunc.touches.touchstart.x < swipeFunc.touches.touchmove.x ? "right" : "left";

                                // DO STUFF HERE
                                if(swipeFunc.touches.direction === "left")
                                        alert(swipeFunc.touches.direction); 
                                    else if(swipeFunc.touches.direction === "left")
                                        alert(swipeFunc.touches.direction);
                                    else
                                        return true;
                                return false;
                            }
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        init: function() {
            document.addEventListener('touchstart', swipeFunc.touchHandler, false); 
            document.addEventListener('touchmove', swipeFunc.touchHandler, false);  
            document.addEventListener('touchend', swipeFunc.touchHandler, false);
        }
    };
swipeFunc.init();
```

Comment: After an additional test, it's the swipe function that block everything. Removing it and having only the other part of the code works fine. But of course I would like it to work.